# Mongoose Not Editing

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So I am working on a little site with my friends. And we keep running into an annoying issue with mongoose. So we have editing collections working but for some reason 1 part of our collections are not editing.

```
if (req.body.type=="img") {
      users.update({username: req.user.username}, {
        IMG:req.body.img
        }, function(err, affected, resp) {
    res.redirect("/profiles/"+req.params.profile);
    })
}
```

that is the current code we are using. We have pretty much the same thing setup for editing other parts of our DB. We have tested and req.body.img is defined all the other variables we use. Plus we know the IMG part collection is stored as we use it for other things. But when we try to redefine it nothing happens.

Comment: Is `IMG` defined in the schema for `users`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you intended to do is to update the document that satisfies username==req.user.username but what your code actually does is turning

```
{ username: "some username" }
```

into

```
{ IMG: "some_img" } // or whatver data you have for req.body.img
```

What you should have done is

```
users.update({
    username: req.user.username
}, {$set: {
    IMG: req.body.img
}}, function(err, affected, resp) {
    res.redirect("/profiles/"+req.params.profile);
})
```

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/ for details